# Powershell script working on Console app but not working on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, iis, skype-for-business

I Have a powershell script to connect on Skype for Business Online and it is working on powershell also on Console application but when I call from ASP.NET not working

The exception when I run through ASP.NET:

"The term 'Get-CsPowerShellEndpoint' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again"

```html
string command = @"$PlainPassword ='****';
                                    $UserName = '****';
                                    $SecurePassword = $PlainPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString-AsPlainText -Force;
                                    $SkypeOnlineCred = New - Object - TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $SecurePassword;
                                    Remove-Variable -Name PlainPassword;
                                    Remove-Variable -Name SecurePassword;
                                    Remove-Variable -Name UserName;
                                    $SkypeOnlineSession = New-CsOnlineSession Credential $SkypeOnlineCred;
                                         Import-PSSession -Session $SkypeOnlineSession | Out-Null;";

var initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] {
                    "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Skype for Business Online\\Modules\\SkypeOnlineConnector\\SkypeOnlineConnectorStartup.psm1"
                 });

                
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial))
{
 // Open runspace 
 runspace.Open();

 // Initialize PowerShell engine
 using (PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create())
 {
  shell.Runspace = runspace;
  

  // Add the script to the PowerShell object
  shell.Commands.AddScript(command);
  try
  {
   // Execute the script
   var results = shell.Invoke();

   if (shell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
   {
    throw new Exception(shell.Streams.Error[0].Exception.Message);
   }
   // display results, with BaseObject converted to string
   // Note : use |out-string for console-like output
   return results;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   throw new Exception("On Invoke" + e.Message);
  }          
 }
}
```

Comment: Try using a different SfB PS cmdlet -- if it says the same thing then your module isn't loading like you think it should be.

Comment: After importing the module. Could you please give a sleep for 5 seconds and see the result.